# Git deleting files on merge

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using atlassian source tree to manage my git work.  I have a master, develop and release branch.  I have created files on my develop branch which do not exist in master.  I used my develop branch to create my release.  I am done with my release and have clicked on finish release.  The problem is now that I have done the merge, the files i have create no longer exist in the merge.  I do not understand how this is possible.  Does anyone know how this might occur?